# How to get viewers in google spreadsheet using google's api client v3

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to retrieve all viewers for each of the spreadsheets in my drive. 
For that I am using python and google's api client. I have managed to retrieve from the File objet the sheet's name, owner and other info, but I cannot find a way to retrieve its viewers.

Code so far:

```py
page_token=None
while True:
    a = service.files().list(
                    q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'",
                    corpora='allDrives',
                    includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
                    supportsAllDrives=True,
                    fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, owners, lastModifyingUser, modifiedTime)',
                    pageToken=page_token
                    ).execute()

    for file in a.get('files', []):
            print('Found file: %s (%s) %s' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = a.get('nextPageToken', None)

    if page_token is None:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the viewers (reader) of files in Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with python.
- You have already been able to get the metadata from the files in Google Drive.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In order to retrieve the viewers from the file, add `permissions` to `fields`.
- I think that an error occurs at `print('Found file: %s (%s) %s' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows. Please think of this as just one of several modifications.

```
page_token = None
while True:
    a = service.files().list(
        q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'",
        corpora='allDrives',
        includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
        supportsAllDrives=True,
        fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, owners, lastModifyingUser, modifiedTime, permissions)',  # Modified
        pageToken=page_token
    ).execute()

    for file in a.get('files', []):
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))  # Modified

        # I added below script for showing the viewers.
        for permission in file.get('permissions', []):
            if permission['role'] == 'reader':
                print("Viewer of %s: type is %s. email is %s." % (file.get('name'), permission.get('type'), permission.get('emailAddress')))

    page_token = a.get('nextPageToken', None)

    if page_token is None:
        break
```

#### References:

- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)
- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer that was what I was looking for, do you happen to know if I can also retrieve a last viewed date?

Comment: @Saraki Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, there is `viewedByMeTime` in the fields. But I'm not sure whether this is what you want. So could you please check it? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) If that was not the result you want, I have to apologize.

Comment: I have read the documentation for the File component, no unfortunately I was looking something for the general usage of the files not only by me. What I wanted to check was when was the last time that the file was opened in general so as if it is not used anymore to delete it. You were very helpful with your answer though.

Comment: @Saraki Thank you for replying. As other method, how about using `modifiedTime`? In this case, when the file is modified, `modifiedTime` is changed. Using this, for example, how about modifying Spreadsheet using [the OnOpen event trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#available_types_of_triggers)? By using this, when the Spreadsheet is opened, it changes the Spreadsheet. For example, put "sample" to a cell and delete "sample". By this, `modifiedTime` is changed, and you can retrieve it as the last view time. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Is it possible to get the full code for this snippet? I'm trying to do this myself, and it sounds as though this might be exactly what I need... but I don't know what `service` is, or what else needs to be initiated beforehand. Thanks in advance!